# eGit Merge Resolution - Use Your Copy

Tags: git, egit, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I still new to eGit. I'm trying to figure out how on earth to get eGit to resolve a merge conflict using my copy, no change. I'm referring to the notes on the eGit Wiki:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Possible_merge_results

However, when I add my copy to resolve the conflict, eGit still leaves the diff marks in the file "<<<<<<< HEAD", "=======", ">>>>>>>". The doc says to add after using Merge-Tool:

> edit the working tree version until you are happy with it Team > Add
>   the merged resource to mark the conflict as resolved commit the merge
>   commit via Team > Commit

However, it still leaves the diff marks in the file after I've resolved the conflict using my copy, which really results in no change, and therefore, requires no save. My question is how do I get eGit to accept, add, and commit my copy without leaving the diff markers in the file? Will these markers go away at the final commit?

Comment: "therefore, requires no save" -> so I'm assuming you used the option "Use HEAD" in the merge tool dialog? If you can't save the left side after choosing this option, it seems like a bug in EGit. If this is the case I'd suggest filing a bug report.

Comment: Yep, chose the option "Use HEAD". Oh well, I'll check the bug board, see if it's a known issue or add.

Comment: K, if anybody else would like to see this resolved, I've entered a bug here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374790. There is a related issue, but not identical: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322537

Comment: Ok, thanks for the bug report. By the way, it's "EGit", not "eGit".

Comment: This problem looks like the same I just [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240953/how-to-revert-changes-due-to-a-merge-with-eclipse-and-egit/33256157#33256157) about, with a different workaround. Thanks for the bug report, I just voted for it. Not cool that the bug is still there after 3.5+ years though.

Answer (score 3):

While the bug is solved, do what is suggested on the bug comments

> Frank Jakop CLA 2013-07-08 09:53:34 EDT We wold very appreciate this
>   too, at the moment we have to "workaround" by inserting and then
>   deleting a space in the file, save and add to index.